# Spark convert array of structs to Vector for Euclidean distance

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-mllib

Hi I have the following dataset column:

```
+-----------------------+
|hashes                 |
+-----------------------+
|[[-7.0], [0.0], [5.0]] |
|[[-8.0], [1.0], [1.0]] |
|[[-6.0], [1.0], [1.0]] |
+-----------------------+
```

which has been generated by:

```scala
val brp = new BucketedRandomProjectionLSH().
          setBucketLength(2).
          setNumHashTables(3).
          setInputCol("features").
          setOutputCol("hashes")

val model = brp.fit(dfVa)
val dfHash = model.transform(dfVa)
```

With the following schema:

```
|-- hashes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: vector (containsNull = true)
```

I'd like to make a cross join to another dataset with the same column and calculate the euclidean distance with a UDF I made:

```scala
val euclideanDistance = udf { (v1: Vector, v2: Vector) =>
        sqrt(Vectors.sqdist(v1, v2))
}

cookesWb
   .join(cookesNext)
   .withColumn("Distance", euclideanDistance(
        cookesWb.col("hashes"),
        broadcast(cookesNext.col("hashes"))
   ))
   .filter(col("Distance").lt(80))
```

However I get the following error:

```
cannot resolve 'UDF(hashes, hashes)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires vector type, however, '`hashes`' is of array<struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>>
```

Do you know how to convert that messy type to a Vector in order to let me  execute the function?
Thanks.

Comment: can you share the schema of dataframe? what is the key to join two dataset?

Comment: It is a cross join, I shouldn't need any key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you have an Array of sparkML vectors. To be able to use your UDF, you first need to convert that to a vector. We can define another UDF for this.

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}
val toVect = udf { (x : WrappedArray[Vector]) =>
    // we flatten the array of vectors
    val flatArray : Array[Double] = x.flatMap(_.toArray).toArray 
    Vectors.dense(flatArray)
}
```

NB: `Array[Vector]` would not work here. When you manipulate arrays in spark and use UDFs, `WrappedArray` is the type you need to use.

Then you can just perform your `crossJoin` like this for instance:

```scala
df
  .crossJoin(df2)
  .withColumn("d", euclideanDistance(toVect(df.col("hashes")),
                                     toVect(df2.col("hashes"))))
  .show()
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, however your solution is not working as  `argument 1 requires array<double> type, however, 'hashes' is of array<struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>>`

Comment: My bad. I misread the schema. So it is an array, of structures, who themselves contain an array. That does not really look like what you have in the df you showed... Can you be more specific about what you are trying to compare, and how that data is stored in `hashes`?

Comment: That "hashes" column has been generated by by `BucketedRandomProjectionLSH()` model which is from Spark mllib I need to aggregate similar rows by calculating their distance

Comment: You should specify all this in your question. That's very valuable for people who try to answer, and to people who will have similar problems in the future and come across this post ;-)